# link inside Template literals inside a clickable div does not work(It seems like I can't stop the page from reloading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I need to be able to do this, But the onClick function is not recognized as a function, but as a string. The output is

{ e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault() history.push('/profile/test') }}>@test

with @test being the ${newmes}.

``` newText=testmessage.replace(/@[a-z]+/i,`<p onClick={(e)=>{

```
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault()
 history.push(\x27/profile/${username}\x27)}>${newmes}</p></strong>`)
```

let texte=document.getElementById('posttext')

texte.innerHTML=newText```

And if I just want to call a function inside the onClick, like this: onClick={handleclick}. Then I get an error saying "handleclick is not defined at HTMLParagraphElement.onclick".

So how can I fix this? I need to do this because I want the woord beginning with a @ to be a link inside a string. And that string is inside a div thats also clickable, thats why I need to use e.stopPropagation();
. So if I just use a `<a></a>` then the link works fine, but because it is inside a clickable div I need to have a onClick function I think.

Im sorry for my bad english, I hope someone has an answer.

EDIT:

So I made the newText as: `` newText=testmessage.replace(/@[a-z]+/i,`<strong><a id=\x22clicke\x22 >${newmes} </a></strong>`) ``

And I added a eventListener to the link like this:

```
 useEffect(()=>{
             let isSubscribed = true
var toggle = document.getElementById('clicke')

if(toggle!=null&&isSubscribed){
    
toggle.addEventListener('click',checklinkclick)
return ()=>{
            
            toggle.removeEventListener('click',checklinkclick)
        }  
}

return () => isSubscribed = false
         })

         const checklinkclick=(e)=>{
             
   e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault()
    
     
  history.push(`/profile/${newname}`)
  
  
  
         }
```

It kinda works, but the ${newname} shows only for one second and then dissapears, although Im using e.preventDefault() to prevent reloading right?

EDIT:

It works now, I had to use e.stopImmediatePropagation()

Answer (score -1):

Add the following line in the constructor of the component. if this is state component,

```
this.handleclick = this.handleclick.bind(this)
```

Add the following line in the same onCLick, if this is a stateless component,

```
onClick={() => handleClick()}
```

Try the above....

Comment: It isn't a stateless component, it is a string being assigned to `innerHTML`

Comment: onClick={() => handleClick()}

Add the above, it will work

Comment: No, it won't. `innerHTML` doesn't support JSX.

Comment: Im using a reactFunctionalExportComponent. So I need a reactClassExportComponent to be able to bind the handleclick to the component?

Comment: It works now! I had to use e.stopImmediatePropagation() instead of e.stopPropagation();